# Не отображается содержимое страницы вывода постов в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь натянуть верстку на вордпресс, но на странице вывода постов содержимое созданное в админке отказывает выводится. Искал информацию два дня и нашел похожую проблему на сайте поддержки, но там все тоже размыто объяснено. Прошу вас объяснить, где я косячу.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- post navigation -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- no post found -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Вывожу контент через обычный цикл, на других страницах сайта работает, а именно на странице вывода постов выводится контент постов без содержимого страницы.

Comment: что значит "контент постов без содержимого страницы"? Какое "содержимое страницы" не выводится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу, что вы хотите вывести содержимое страницы, которую в настройках Wordpress указали как страницу записей.
В главном цикле этого сделать не получится, т. к. в соответствии с вышеупомянутыми настройками основной запрос страницы на странице записей выполняется с параметрами, выбирающими записи из блога.
Но вы можете получить `ID` этой страницы и потом делать с ним что-то, исходя из ваших целей.

```
<?php
$page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts');
?>
```

И далее, например, получаем и выводим контент

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content(null, false, $page_for_posts);
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
echo $content;
?>
```

Либо получаем все данные страницы:

```
<?php
$this_page = get_post($page_for_posts);
var_dump($this_page);
?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо